# How to add a Custom MetaData to a PNG or JPG file

Tags: c#, png, metadata, jpeg, taglib

I can add custom meta data to mp3 mp4 formats with the taglib library but i cant add custom meta data to jpg, png formats with the taglib library
How to add a custom metada to png or jpg file?

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code that isn't working for you?

Answer (score 0):

Here you've got official examples:
https://github.com/mono/taglib-sharp

```
var tfile = TagLib.File.Create(@"C:\My picture.jpg");
string title = tfile.Tag.Title;
var tag =  tfile.Tag as TagLib.Image.CombinedImageTag;
DateTime? snapshot = tag.DateTime;
Console.WriteLine("Title: {0}, snapshot taken on {1}", title, snapshot);

// change title in the file
tfile.Tag.Title = "my new title";
tfile.Save();
```

Should work just fine.

Comment: I can't add in custom meta

Comment: @MehmetCeylan Any details ?

Comment: I want to make tfile.Tag.["MyAttribute"]="Custom Data";